# JSF commandButton disabled - doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton

I have a problem with the function that disables the button. When I click button number one and it does not return the expected value - empty file, I want that button number two should be turned off.
However, it is not. The button number two is turns on and lets you download an empty file. What am I doing wrong?

file.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton value="Button1" update="@form" actionListener="#{test.generate}" ajax="true" />

<p:commandButton value="Button2" actionListener="#{test.download}" ajax="false" disabled="#{test.disableButton} />"

public boolean getDisableButton() {
    return result == null ? true : false;
  }
```

Comment: Is it possible, that your "result" variable is never null? try to debug it

Comment: [mcve] please...